# How do I set an environment variable with NMake?

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

I'm making a makefile using NMake.  I have a few utility programs that run to transform one file into a CPP file.  The utility requires a specific windows environment variable to be set during the session.  Can I set this variable within the Makefile or do I need to create a batch script that sets the variables before it calls NMake?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `!if [set ...]` [trick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/executing-a-program-in-preprocessing?view=vs-2019):

```
!if [set myvar=1]
!endif

# Macro values are fine, too, of course:
MYVAL=preprocessed
!if [set myvar=$(MYVAL)]
!endif

# Proof that myvar has really become an env. var. (see the output):
myvar=This is propagated to the env now!
mymacro=(But this isn't, of course.)

# This handy form works, too:
!if [set myA=1] || [set myB=2]
!endif

# But this will *NOT* make myX an env. var., if it hasn't been set yet:
!if [set myX=$(myX)]
!endif
myX=So you'll not see this...

all:
    set my
```

Output:

```
D:\tmp>nmake -f test.mak

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.21.27702.2
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        set my
myA=1
myB=2
myvar=This is propagated to the env now!
```

Answer (score 0):

An environment variable `ENVAR` that exists when you invoke `nmake` is inherited
as an `nmake` macro of the same name. If you change the value of `ENVVAR` in the
makefile, like:

```
ENVAR=newval
```

then environment variable `ENVAR` assumes the value `newval` for commands
that are run by the makefile. The target:

```
foo:
    echo "%ENVAR%"
```

will echo `newval`.

But you can't *create* an environment variable `ENVAR` like that. So you'll
have to at least create the environment variable you want to use prior to
invoking `nmake`

Comment: _"you'll have to ... create the environment variable ... prior to invoking nmake"_  Luckily, that's not quite true; please see my answer.